# Autodeploy selected image from image repository

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, deployment

We have many Raspberry pi deploys where we are manually cloning sd cards.
Is there a tool like net boot for RPI or a autodeploy solution?

Something like extremly small linux image that know how to go to a predefined location mount and install image and delete itself?

Something that you can set 10-100 rpi's on a network and they autoimage themselves?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is actually two ways (*that I know!*) for do what you want.

I only play with the **[WTWare](https://winterminal.com/)** system, is easy to work but (I think) demand a lot of bandwidth and only work with Windows as OS guest.

The other one is **[RPiTC](http://rpitc.blogspot.com/)**, work (as I read) flawlessly with Linux (**Debian**).

I hope that I (at least) pointed you to the right direction.